# How do I update all but first and last of records with specific foreign key value in rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called `AttendanceLog(time-stamp, employee id, and type: check-in, check-out or undefined)`.

I am trying to run a daily job that finds the records corresponding to an employee who has an odd number of attendance logs and I want to update all but the first and last `attendance_logs` to be of type undefined.

Example:

```
id: 2, logged_at: 9:00, employee_id: 2 
id: 3, logged_at: 11:00, employee_id: 2
id: 4, logged_at: 14:00, employee_id: 2
```

Because employee 2 has 3 `attendance_logs`, I want to modify the ones in between the first and last to be `undefined` in as less # of queries as possible

Comment: can you please share your code of associations?

Comment: AttendanceLog is my only model inside of rails. The table of employees is maintained outside of rails' schema. So it's actually a foreign key only in a logical sense. Meaning there aren't any rails associations between employees and their attendance logs. I use where clauses.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a class method as follows:

```
def self.within_rec(emp_id)
 sef.where(employee_id: emp_id).where.not(id: [self.first.id,self.last.id])
end
```

And you may call this using `AttendanceLog.within_rec(*your employee id*)`

Comment: Well great! Thanks. How do I select the AttendanceLogs though, that have an odd count for one employee_id?
I understand the question doesn't emphasize I want that as part of the answer too. I'll try editing it.

Comment: I understand I can use a where clause with employee_id. I am talking about detecting the employee_ids where the count of attendance logs is odd, does it have to be done in a separate query?